# How can I get Elastic IP/host from KIbana interface

Tags: elasticsearch

Through Kibana interface, how can I get Elastic IP/host?
I mean, the Elastic host which kibana is connected to.
Is that even possible? i'm struggling on that for hours and I got nothing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kibana always connects to the elastic host that is mentioned within `kibana.yml` file that been used during installation/configuration (example value within file as follows):

```
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
```

In case if it configure to points to multiple elastic nodes for high availability of kibana (as follows). Requests to available hosts will be routed in a round robin fashion (top to the bottom of a list and then starting again)

```
elasticsearch.hosts: 
 - http://es-host1:9200
 - http://es-host2:9200
```

To know available nodes, you may use [nodes API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-info.html) from Kibana - Dev tools

```
GET /_nodes

# or Use following
GET /_cat/nodes?v
```

Comment: invoking nodes API from Kibana Dev Tools did a trick! Thank you!!!